# Flutter [iOS] - Create plugin which uses plugins

Tags: ios, flutter

I've created a plugin to use in one of our Flutter apps.
This plugin uses another two plugins: [keyboard visibility](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_visibility) and [url launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher).

When I execute the example app within the plugin project everything works fine but, when I import our plugin project in our app, then this transitive dependencies fail when registering native code:

> [VERBOSE-1:callback_cache.cc(132)] Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore
>   flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   flutter: The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
>   flutter: github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility:
>   flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel
>   flutter: github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility)
>   flutter:
>   flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   flutter: #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:300:7)
>   flutter: 
>   flutter: #1      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream. (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:490:29)
>   flutter: 
>   flutter: #6      new KeyboardVisibilityNotification (package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart:40:92)

This happened in both Android & iOS platforms. I fixed the Android part by adding the native code register, but in iOS it's still failing:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import os

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
            return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

[...]
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: `"This plugin uses another two plugins: keyboard visibility and url launcher."` so you have some native code (java/kotlin) in your plugin and from that code you want to use native code of another plugin?

Comment: Not exactly @pskink, so the flow is: My flutter app > Use My flutter plugin > (From Dart code) Use other plugins (keyboard visibility)

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @svprdga have you coped with it?

Comment: Sorry @IlyaMaximencko, it's been a long time and I don't remember which was the outcome of the problem.